# BigQuery Select data based on Start Index and Last Index

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using below code to get the data from BigQuery.

```
public class BQTEST {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String datasetName = "mydataset";
        String tableName = "mytable";
        String projectId = "gcs";
        String query =
                "SELECT id, " +
                        "qtr, " +
                        "sales, " +
                        "year " +
                        "FROM `gcs.mydataset.mytable` " +
                        ;
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId)
                .setCredentials(
                        ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new
                                FileInputStream("20a3c78f8388.json"))
                )
                .build().getService();
        TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectId, datasetName, tableName);
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration
                .newBuilder(query)
                .build();
        try {
            bigquery.query(queryConfig);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        TableResult results = bigquery.listTableData(
                tableId,
                BigQuery.TableDataListOption.pageSize(1),
                BigQuery.TableDataListOption.startIndex(5)
        );

        for (FieldValueList row : results.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.printf(
                    "ID: %s qtr: %s sales: %s year: %s\n", row.get(0).getValue(), row.get(1).getValue(), row.get(2).getValue(), row.get(3).getValue());
        }


    }
}
```

`BigQuery.TableDataListOption.startIndex(5)` -- This will help to read data from 5th index, index starts from 0.

But I want to read data in chunks like the first 10 records in one process, then the next 20 records in another process and etc.

Trying to read data from a very big table in a parallel process. It's a Truncate/Load table. So no partitions and date range to read data.

I am not able to find a way to give `LAST_INDEX` value in any of the BigQuery Methods.

Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `LAST_INDEX` method you can you for the pagination, as you can check in the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.54.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.TableDataListOption.html).

About your request:

> I want to read data in chunks like the first 10 records in one process, then the next 20 records in another process and etc.,

Using python you can use some parameters as `max_results` and `start_index` to perform it, but in java the only way will be paginating on your query, and change it for each process. So for each process in parallel you will have a different query.

So, each process will have to:

1. Order by some field (or by all the fields) to guarantee every query will return the data in the same order
2. Paginate using `limit` and `offset`:

i.e:

```java
String query = "SELECT id, qtr, sales, year FROM `gcs.mydataset.mytable` " +
               "ORDER BY id, qtr, sales, year " +
               "LIMIT 10 " +
               "OFFSET " + String.valueOf(process_number * 10)
;
```

Process 0 will have lines 0-9 (limit 10 offset 0); 
Process 1 will have lines 10-19 (limit 10 offset 10)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Response. Yes. it worked. But OFFSET and LIMIT will be overhead for larger tables especially with a total recount of more than billions. Is there any other Best way we can achieve this chunking process?

Comment: Bigquery should be able to easily handle billions of rows using offset and limit, it should not be a problem. In your case, as you want to process those rows locally using java, that will be your bottle neck. I would suggest you to process your data directly on bigquery and return only the results. Or, if you want a parallel process and more complex tasks I would suggest you use spark in a cluster. Processing billions rows one by one in your own managed java code may not be the best.

Comment: Hi @ewertonvsilva , Is order by is mandatory if I am not worried about ordering ? can u suggest ? getting resourcesExceeded issue while running query with order by.

Comment: Hi! Yes, its necessary to force Bigquery to return always the dataset in the same order  to enable the pagination. If you don't use it, the query can return the data in different order and the use of limit/offset will have no sense.

Comment: Thank You. The following question is not related to this. kindly advise if I should create separate ticket. How best we can handle rateLimitExceed Issue. facing more often.